# What can cause spinOnce to stop processing messages?

Tags: ros, callback, roscpp, nodehandle, spinonce

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to debug a very rare instance (that happens randomly) in my node when I will be waiting for a specific message and it never gets received. I've created a very rough code example to help illustrate how things are happening. My actual code has a lot more subscribers and classes, but this should get the point across.

#### Key Points

+ `spinOnce()` is being called inside a `createTimer()` callback
+ Messages are not being added to subscribers queue. (verified)
+ Messages are being published by publisher. (verified)
+ After the `TimerCallback()` function completes, messages will get received again.

#### Publisher Node:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "Publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  ros::Rate r(1);
  publisher = node->advertise<Message_type>(topic_string, 1, true);
  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    count++;
    publisher.publish(Message_type(count));
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

#### Subscriber Node:

bool message_received_ = false;
    
    void ImportantCallback(const Message_type& msg)
    {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("count: " subscribe(topic_string, 1, ImportantCallback, this);
      InitializeSubscribers(node);
    
      plan_timer_ = node->createTimer
        (ros::Duration(0.01), &TimerCallback, this);
    
      while (ros::ok())
      {
        ros::spinOnce();
        r.sleep();
      }
    }

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259765/what-can-cause-spinonce-to-stop-processing-messages?/) by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recursively calling spinOnce() can be dangerous. You might end up calling your `TimerCallback()` recursively, particularly with the timer's duration being so short.

As an alternative to recursively calling `spinOnce()`, you could try using a separate callback queue for the timer. See here for how this works:

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Advanced:_Using_Different_Callback_Queues

If you want to ignore all data received on other topics until a particular message is received, there might be better ways to do it. For example removing subscribers (`sub.shutdown()`) and re-creating them when ready to handle data again - although this is costly in destroying and setting up connections. Another would be a flag that tells other subscriber callbacks to ignore all received data until that particular message is received.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-04-21**:
I had performed some experiments and found out that the timer callbacks are specially handled. I.e. once you're in a timer callback function, a call to `spinOnce()` will not trigger another time callback until your timer callback function has completed.

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-04-21**:
It seems the problem might have been fixed by avoiding the use of the timer callbacks, but I don't understand why. I also did some experiments to test the limit on recursively calling `spinOnce()` inside my callbacks (with the use of infinite loops). It seemed that, aside from the timer callback...

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-04-21**:
`spinOnce()` functioned as normal.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
Yeah, I made a mistake when I was reading the code and docs. It turns out that the `CallbackQueue` class is actually designed to handle things like callbacks calling the queue again. See #9 in http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Internals . So the first part of my answer is wrong, I think.